# Show all of the implications and equivalences between the following relationships.

Tags: logic, equivalence-relations

A: $x=y$, B: $x^2 = y^2$, C: $xy=x^2$, D: $xy=y^2$

The answers are:
$$A \implies B$$
$$A \implies C$$
$$A \implies D$$

I don't understand how $A \iff C$ among others is not an answer, there is no way $xy=x^2$ can be true if $x=y$ is not true...

Comment: Sorry, had a typo in B. Fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand how A $\Longleftrightarrow $C among others is not an answer, there is no way $xy=x^2$ can be true if $x=y$ is not true...

*Hint:* Choose $x = 0$.

Comment: Well... this is embarasing